# Yii cdbcommand share my table information

Tags: php, mysql, yii

When we use cdbCommand in yii and get error cdb command returned my table information ,this is a security problem how can resolve it?

Comment: This needs more detail. Provide some code blocks, some results, what you mean about why it's a security problem, etc.

Comment: when send a ajax request with a invalid id for scurity test in the console get error like this "can not add or update a chile row a foreign key constraint fail (my_table_name  constraint foreign_key_name ... )"

Comment: Please put that detail in your question, with steps to reproduce your problem, and possibly some screenshots.

Comment: i have a field foreign key to id from another tabel and when send ajax with invalid id return above error ,error is correct but i have to hide this becuase its security problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to

```
define('YII_DEBUG', false);
```

Also check your config/main.php for

```
'authManager' => array(
  'showErrors' => YII_DEBUG
),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i have define('YII_DEBUG', false); in my index.php